# Mp3 file link in popup window inside php code

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to make media files links open in a new popup window. Here is the code that needs to be edited:

```
$lib_element .= '<a target="_self" href="/downloads/' . $level3['meta']['audio_file'] . '"><div class="lib_element_audio"></div></a>';
```

That code is part of custom Joomla mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$lib_element .= '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.open(\'/downloads/'.$level3['meta']['audio_file'].'\', \'Titletext\', \'width=400, height=200, resizable, status, scrollbars=1, location\');">Open File<div class = "lib_element_audio"></div></a> ';
```